# Absolute value with inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

Can we solve the following

$ |f(x)| + |g(x) | < b$

by  taking the intersection of the solutions for

$f(x) + g(x) < b$

$-f(x) - g(x) < b$

$f(x) - g(x) < b$

$-f(x) + g(x) < b$

Comment: A little hint, $a<b$ implies that $-a>-b$

Comment: it is too little :(

Comment: Yes. It is an equivalence. (And fairly straightforward to show!)

Comment: I just  want to make sure. Thanks.